# Amazon EC2 / RStudio : Is there are a way to run a job without maintaining a connection?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I have a long running job that I'd like to run using `EC2` + `RStudio`.  I setup the `EC2` instance then setup `RStudio` as a page on my web browser.  I need to physically move my laptop that I use to setup the connection and run the web browser throughout the course of the day and my job gets terminated in `RStudio` but the instance is still running on the `EC2` dashboard.

Is there a way to keep a job running without maintaining an active connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original concern that it needed to maintain a live connection was incorrect.  It turns out the error was from running out of memory, it just coincided with being disconnected from the internet connection.

An instance is started from the AWS dashboard and stopped or terminated from there also.  As long as it is still running it can be accessed from an RStudio tab by copying the public DNS to the address bar on the web page and logging in again.

Answer (score 9):

Does it have to be started / controlled via RStudio?

If you make your task a "normal" R script, executed via Rscript or littler, then you can run them from the shell ... and get to

- use old-school tools like `nohup`, `batch` or `at` to control running in the background
- use tools like `screen`, `tmux` or `byobu` to *maintain one or multiple sessions* in which you launch the jobs, and connect / disconnect / reconnect at leisure.

RStudio Server works in similar ways but AFAICT limits you to a single user per user / machine -- which makes perfect sense for interactive work but is limiting if you have a need for multiple sessions.

FWIW, I like byobu with tmux a lot for this.